# I am getting an error while assigning a value to the interface I have defined

Tags: angular, typescript

Hello everyone probably a very simple mistake but i couldn't figure it out

```
 Ids: [
      {
        key: number
      }
    ],
```

this part is my definition on interface side
and then i am sending the id like this

```
const Ids = this.selectedDocuments.map(id => ({ key: id }))
```

and i get this error

> Type '{ key: any; }[]' is not assignable to type '[{ key: number; }]'.
> Target requires 1 element(s) but source may have fewer.

Thanks in advance for everyone's help.

Answer (score 1):

If you want `Ids` to be an array of { key: number } interface, the above definition should be `const Ids: { key: number }[] = [];` instead of `{[key: number]}`.

Edit: You should check the answer @liel-fridman 's as well to make sure whatever you're passing is converted to number if `selectedDocuments` doesn't have a type or if it contains numeric "strings".

Comment: This is one part of the problem :) the other is that TS doesn't know that the array it gets from the map function has only numbers in the id keys

Comment: I thought this comment was from the OP, sorry. I deleted my comment. I've realised that after I saw your answer ^^.

Comment: interface Ids: { key: number}[] I fixed the interface ids defination like this, it worked.

Answer (score 1):

You have two mistakes here.

First, I assume you want your IDs to be objects with one element - a key. Then, you should do as @archon said. In addition, you can use casting, like this:

```
const Ids = this.selectedDocuments.map(id => ({ key: +id }))
```

to make sure the ids are converted to numbers and this should hopefully be enough for TS to figure out what you're trying to do.